Multi DB Access In Rails 6 + Heroku
There is a Rails 5 application that runs in Heroku; it has two DBs, a Primary and a Follower (read-only), the follower is the replica of the Primary. In some application areas, we use followers to get the data. Previously, rails didn't support Multi DB, so we used the Gem Octopus. However, they put it in maintenance mode as the Rails 6 supports the Multi DB.
We used different ways to access the follower db through octopus like:
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end




class SetupController < ApplicationController
  around_action :select_follower

  def select_follower(&block)
    Octopus.using(ENV['FOLLOWER_DB'], &block)
  end

  def method1
   // enter code here
  end
end




@customer = Customer.using(FOLLOWER_DB).find(params[:id])




Octopus.using(:master) do
  SidekiqWorker.perform_async(param1, param2)
end

It was working fine and this has been running for more than 5 years.
Recently We have migrated our Rails application to Rails 6 from 5 and we replaced the octopus with multi DB setup.
database.yml
production:
 primary:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
 secondary:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['FOLLOWER_DATABASE_URL'] %>
  migrations_paths: db/secondary_migrate

app/models/application_record.rb
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  connects_to database: { writing: :primary, reading: :primary }
end

app/models/secondary_application_record.rb
class SecondaryApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  connects_to database: { writing: :secondary, reading: :secondary }
end

Then when we try to access the follower as we done the same way with octopus, like
class DashboardController < ApplicationController

  around_action :select_secondary_db

  def select_secondary_db(&block)
    SecondaryApplicationRecord.connected_to(role: :reading, &block)
  end

  def method1
   // enter code here
  end
end

or
SecondaryApplicationRecord.connected_to(role: :reading) do
  Customer.find_by_id(params[:id])
end

In all this new way, the logs shows the query runs in primary db, nothing runs through follower/secondary DB. What could be the case that run always through primary?

I am assuming Customer inherits from ApplicationRecord and as such it uses the reading role defined. You could try using the sharding  syntax instead. Docs. It says it is for horizontal sharding but it seems like it should work fine for vertical sharding.
